# Python Pandas drop rows based on a column's data type

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to drop the rows that is not a float type in one column, how to do that? Thanks in advance.

```
         a     b    c 
    1   1.2   2.2   3.3
    2   rvtg  1.2   2.2
    3   2.2   2.2   1.6
```

as cell "a2" is rvtg, not a float, so i'd like to drop row 2, I tried several code but it gives error msg, could anyone pls help? thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply pd.to_numeric and drop NaNs. Please note that this is a more generic solution. If you know which column is expected to have non-numeric values, you can avoid using apply.

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce').dropna()

    a   b   c
1   1.2 2.2 3.3
3   2.2 2.2 1.6
```

Edit: Since only column `a` is likely to contain non-numeric values, a more efficient solution would be to convert column `a` to numeric rather than applying the function to all the columns. The following will return same output.

```
df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors = 'coerce')
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```